# Maven repositories priority if both contains repositories?

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven. if i have repositories in both `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` then which one is given priority?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both work together
[example here](http://maven.apache.org/examples/injecting-properties-via-settings.html)

Comment: Do u mean it it will look into both repositories mentioned in settings.xml and pom.xml? Thanks!